# Count nodes in SPARQL property path to find nearest node of type

Tags: sparql, rdf, graphdb

[Image of example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK3SV.png)

I have an RDF graph, representing duct networks. All components are connected with the symmetric property `exchangesFluidWith` (see picture for example).
For all air terminals, I would like to find the nearest Mechanical Damper, no matter if it is 5 nodes away or 100 nodes away. I suppose property paths are the way to go, but is there a way to count the number of steps and choose the one with the fewest?
I thought about introducing an intermediary node between the damper and the air terminal and sort by `count(?intermediary)`, but since the `exchangesFluidWith` is symmetric, all components in the network will be intermediary, as I understand.

Any suggestions?

```
PREFIX ex: <https://example.com/ex#>
select ?damper where { 
    ?airTerminal a ex:AirTerminal .
    ?airTerminal ex:exchangesFluidWith* ?damper .
    ?damper a ex:MechanicalDamper .
    ?airTerminal fso:exchangesFluidWith* ?intermediary .
    ?intermediary fso:exchangesFluidWith* ?damper .
    ?damper a fso:MechanicalDamper .
} group by ?damper order by (count(?intermediary)) limit 1
```

Comment: in your cyclic data the number of paths between two nodes would be infinite - that's the worst case scenario for property paths of course - and shortest path isn't really possible with SPARQL - there would be more suited graph traversal languages like Cypher, Gremlin etc.

Comment: other than that, you could try two workaround from Jushua Taylor posted here some years ago: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31048247/calculate-length-of-path-betwen-nodes-with-unknown-edges) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024413/finding-all-steps-in-property-path) - but I don't know how good triples stores will work here

Comment: is there a reason for adding the triple in both directions to the data?

Comment: also, for GraphDB I would just make use of their path search extension instead of plain SPARQL: https://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/10.0/graph-path-search.html

Comment: @UninformedUser Since the property is symmetrical, using inference (which I need for other tasks) will create the other direction. In the best case, I can use an asymmetric subproperty (which works just fine), but for robustness, I would like to solve the symmetrical case, but I realize it may not be that easy.

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks for pointing me to the Path Search extension, it looks promising. I will look into that and the other languages you recommend